# Query $match and $project Heavily Nested Data (MongoDB/Aggregation)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need help writing a Mongoose Aggregate Query that `$project`'s a single `business.location.team.member`'s permissions object only. MongoDB's documentation about projecting heavily nested data isn't great so I'm kind of stuck.

**Example Collection:**

```js
const business = [
    {
      b_id: ObjectId("a"),
      locations: [ //can have multiple locations per business
        {
           l_id: ObjectId("b"),
           teams: [ //can have multiple teams per location
               {
                  t_id: ObjectId("c"),
                  members: [ //can have multiple members per team
                        {
                            m_id: ObjectId("d"),
                            permissions: { //each member has a single "permissions" object with different permission objects
                              p1: {
                                a: true,
                                b: false,
                                c: true,
                                d: false,
                              },
                              p2: {
                                a: true,
                                b: false,
                                c: true,
                                d: false,
                              }
                            }
                        }
                  ]
               } 
            ]
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
```

**Desired response:**

```js
const permissions = {
  p1: {
    a: true,
    b: false,
    c: true,
    d: false,
  },
  p2: {
    a: true,
    b: false,
    c: true,
    d: false,
  }
}
```

**Route:**

```js
router.post("/", authUser, (req, res) => {
  const _ids = {
    b_id: req.body.b_id, //business _id === "a"
    l_id: req.body.l_id, //locations _id === "b"
    t_id: req.body.t_id, //teams _id === "c"
    m_id: req.body.m_id, //members _id === "d"
  }
  Business.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        b_id: ObjectId(_ids.b_id),
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
      //how do I project the perms object from the correct member
      },
    },
  ]).then((perms) => {
    console.log(perms);
  });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it's not pretty, but it gets the job done. There's got to be some iterative way to do this?

```js
router.post("/", authUser, (req, res) => {
  const _ids = {
    b_id: req.body.b_id, //business _id === "a"
    l_id: req.body.l_id, //locations _id === "b"
    t_id: req.body.t_id, //teams _id === "c"
    m_id: req.body.m_id, //members _id === "d"
  }
  Business.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        b_id: ObjectId(_ids.b_id),
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$locations",
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "locations.l_id": ObjectId(_ids.l_id),
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$locations.teams",
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "locations.teams.t_id": ObjectId(_ids.t_id),
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$locations.teams.members",
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "locations.teams.members.m_id": ObjectId(_ids.m_id),
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        permissions: ["$locations.teams.members.permissions"],
      },
    },
  ]).then((perms) => {
    res.status(200).json(perms[0].permissions[0]);
  });
});
```